# Add subscribers to Mailchimp using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have been using Google Apps Script to add subscribers to Mailchimp. I have successfully done this earlier this year and the code was working perfectly fine for a few months. I used the code here - https://gist.github.com/acarrillo/5772508

I took a break from this project over summer and now the code is not working. I expected that perhaps I accidentally removed lines of code but upon comparing to the GitHub link, the code looks the same. I have also tried a different API key with no luck.

When I run the code in Apps Script I am getting this error:

> "error":"You must specify a apikey value for the listSubscribe method",
>   "code":-90

Here is the code:

```
function sendToMailChimp(fname, email, url) {
  var payload = {
    "method": "listSubscribe",
    "apikey": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "id": "xxxx",
    "merge_vars[FNAME]": 'test',
    "merge_vars[LEAGUE]": 'hi',
    "email_address": "sunil@test.com",
    "double_optin": false,
    "update_existing": true
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://us16.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe', options);
  //http://us7.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It seems that the error message says the reason of the issue. Can you provide the detail information of the API? Is there the possibility that the specification of the API was changed?

Comment: You seem to be using both URL parameters (i.e. a GET request) and a payload (i.e. a POST request). Please confirm that you are using the correct API endpoint. You may need to pass the API key as a URL parameter.